# writing source of image in variable and using that variable when changing css in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Simple code that works

```
 $(this).css({'background-image':'url(images/icons/accept.png)'});
```

And now the code that doesn't work

```
kkk='images/icons/accept.png';
$(this).css({'background-image':'url(kkk)'});
```

What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a variable name inside a string. Concatenate the strings:

```
kkk='images/icons/accept.png';
$(this).css({'background-image':'url(' + kkk + ')'});
```